# How to capture and record the activity of a SQL table

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a winform app, all the SQL is inline and no stored procedure is used unfortunately.

What is the best way to keep a trail of what action (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) is performed against a SQL table, monitor and capture a record of the activity going on in a **single table**.

I know SQL server profiler is available but ideally I don't want to keep the profiler running all the time, what I need is something running behind the scenes and capturing all the activity for one table.

I thought of using triggers but there are some disadvantages of using it so I was wondering  if there are other options?

Thanks

Comment: Depending on exactly what you want to capture, triggers might be the easiest option to implement. Can you explain what exactly you want to capture, and what specific disadvantages you're concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server 2008 (and up), Change Data Capture sounds like a good place to start:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Note that Change Data Capture is an Enterprise edition feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ORACLE, you can audit a table using this statement (if fireid
is the name of the user doing the updates):

AUDIT SELECT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, INSERT TABLE, DELETE TABLE BY fireid BY ACCESS;

The results will be stored in the SYS.AUD$ table

(If you're using another database just search the documentation for auditing DML statements.)

SQL SERVER: There is a feature called "SQL AUDIT" Is this what you're looking for? 
http://www.bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/

Comment: Unfortunately it is not Oracle. It is MS SQL 2008 R2

Comment: SQL SERVER: There is a feature called "SQL AUDIT" Is this what you're looking for?  See this URL: 
http://www.bradmcgehee.com/2010/03/an-introduction-to-sql-server-2008-audit/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. If you just want to do it in Code (depending on your program)
You can just add the commands to a list and write them to a file.

If you are using EntityFrameWork then I would log the data changes. And use of stored procs is really best when using EF.

A sample of your code or project would help. TransactionLogs already capture that information.

And OBVIOUSLY your using Sql Server THOSE ORACLE PEOPLE ARE JUST SO JEALOUS.

Also look at using DataSourceViews, it's a way to tell what is going on with the server.

Answer (score 0):

I think SQL Server CHANGE TRACKING TeEchinique is best suitable for your requirements.